# Azure B2C Oauth: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm following the tutorial from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code/

I'm unable to continue with the Oauth token aquisition part after signing in and redirecting to the OAuthCallback

here's where I invoke it

```
    public async static Task<AdAcessToken> ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(string userId, string conversationId, string code, string AdOauthCallback)
    {
        var uri = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/baad.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=b2c_1_sign-in");

        var formdata = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", Constants.ADClientId),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "openid offline_access"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", AdOauthCallback)
        });


        var data = new
        {
            grant_type = "authorization_code",
            client_id = Constants.ADClientId,
            scope = "openid offline_access",
            code = code,
            redirect_uri = AdOauthCallback
        };

        return await AdPostRequest<AdAcessToken>(uri,data);
    }
```

Here's my method

```
    private static async Task<T> AdPostRequest<T>(Uri uri, Object data)
    {
        string json;

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "microsoftonline.com";
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var returned = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, data).ConfigureAwait(false);    //SSL ERROR IM STUCK HERE!!!!            
            json = returned.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }

        try
        {
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
            return result;
        }
        catch (JsonException ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Unable to deserialize the AD response.", ex);
        }
    }
```

here's the error output

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>An error occurred while sending the request.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at VSTF_RD_Bot.AdHelpers.<AdPostRequest>d__7`1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\bob\Development\BotFrameworkSample-master\Bot\VSTF_RD_Bot\AdHelpers.cs:line 130 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at VSTF_RD_Bot.AdHelpers.<ExchangeCodeForAccessToken>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\bob\Development\BotFrameworkSample-master\Bot\VSTF_RD_Bot\AdHelpers.cs:line 73 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at VSTF_RD_Bot.Controllers.OAuthCallbackController.<OAuthCallback>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\bob\Development\BotFrameworkSample-master\Bot\VSTF_RD_Bot\Controllers\OAuthCallbackController.cs:line 34 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.WebException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context) at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException
</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

Please advise. I've even done the Powershell step but doesn't seem to be working.

```
Step 5: Trust the IIS Express SSL certificate

Since the web API is SSL protected, the client of the API (the web app) will refuse the SSL connection to the web API unless it trusts the API's SSL certificate. Use the following steps in Windows Powershell to trust the IIS Express SSL certificate. You only need to do this once. If you fail to do this step, calls to the TodoListService will always throw an unhandled exception where the inner exception message is:

"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

To configure your computer to trust the IIS Express SSL certificate, begin by opening a Windows Powershell command window as Administrator.

Query your personal certificate store to find the thumbprint of the certificate for CN=localhost:

PS C:\windows\system32> dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My


    Directory: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\My
```

I am unable to continue. How can I resolve this issue, there doesn't seem to be any updates on the documentation, have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "microsoftonline.com";
```

To this:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "login.microsoftonline.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you debugging your application with Chrome?
If so, try this:
1) Debug with any IE or Firefox
2) When the browser displays the Not Secure warning message, click Advanced.
3) Once in Advanced, search for View Certificate
4) Once you find View Certificate, save it to disk.
5) Stop debugging and start again, but this time with Chrome
6) When the Not Secure warning appears, go to settings of Chrome, Advanced, Manage Certificates
7) Import the saved certificate using the defaults.

This is basically a way of registering a self-signed certificate. There are other ways of doing it so the system will trust on it, but this is what I did here and it worked fine. 
Hope it helps.